# How to access resource file in worker role class

Tags: azure

I am using a worker role in windows azure for sending emails. I have saved the email format in the resource file for the worker role. But i am unable to find a way to use the resources in the resource file. In webapplications one can use `GetLocalResourceObject` but there is nothing like this in worker role.

I have just one default culture resource file.

Comment: I have found the solution.
one can use the resources of the webrole by WebRole1.Properties.Resources.MyResourceName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. one can use the resources of the webrole by `WebRole1.Properties.Resources.MyResourceName`